# Schmitt Trigger voltage divider

Tags: circuit-design, schmitt-trigger

Could someone please explain to me when and why should we add a voltage divider at the inverting input of a Schmidtt Trigger?

[image: Schmidtt Trigger with voltage divider at the inverting input]

Comment: What is the "input" to this circuit? The 2.5V or the 5V? What is the range of voltages for this input?

Comment: The range for the input is 0V to 2.5V. The output is supposed to be 5 for Vin above 2.5V and 0 otherwise, I don't know why we cannot achieve the same result with a simple Schmitt Trigger whose inverting input is connected directly to Vref

Comment: If your circuit is supply from +5V this you need a voltage divider to get 2.5V at inverting input.

Comment: I see, thank you!